# Running server in a goroutine?

Tags: go

I have a Golang service listening for Kafka messages but I also want to start an http server in it just for health checks. Server code is simple:

```
package server

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func Start() {
    port := ":8080"
    r := setupRouter()
    r.Run(port)
}

func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/health", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": "OK"})
    })

    return r
}
```

And in the main function I just call the Start() function.

```
server.Start()
```

Is this fine or should I have done this in a goroutine like:

```
go func(){
   server.Start()
}()
```

There's bunch of other stuff happening in main.go - queue listener are initialized, databases, etc.

Comment: The `Run()` method will block unless an error happens, so thereby `server.Start()` in your main.go will be blocked. If the rest of the execution after that needs to happen, then it needs to happen in a goroutine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a go routine if you don't want the `Run` to block your main thread.

`go server.Start()`